# generating wordcloud with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, word-cloud

I am trying to create a wordcloud from a text file and I need to plot only alphas,

below is the code

```
with open("worldcloud.txt") as f:
count = dict()
for line in f:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.isalpha():
            if word in count:
                count[word] += 1
            else:
                count[word] = 1
cloud = count.WordCloud()
cloud.generate_from_frequencies(cloud)
cloud.to_file("myfile.jpg")
```

But I am facing following error:

> File "cloud.py", line 11, in 
> cloud = count.WordCloud()
> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'WordCloud'

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `count` is a dict and you call `WordCloud()` on it, what do you expect ?

Comment: Sorry to say, but I was asked to generate a dictionary of keys and values, and use wordcloud to plot according to frequencies. Can you tell me WordCloud() belongs to which type?

Comment: You should read the word cloud documentation to learn how to use it: http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/simple.html
What you want might be something like `cloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(count)`

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because your `count` is a simple Python dict which does not have `WordCloud` function.

From the doc of [wordcloud with frequency](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/auto_examples/frequency.html) you should pass the dict to the `generate_from_frequencies` function:

```py
cloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(count)
```

Comment: You're welcome, consider accepting the answer if it has helped solving your problem